# How can I speed up getting a random point from from the difference of two regions?

Tags: performance-tuning, random, regions

I am trying to create a blue point (please see image below) within a small radius of a red point such that the blue point lies outside of the black circle.

[image]

The code thatIi have used to generate the figure is as follows:

```
With[{radius = 0.1},
  Table[
    initpoint = RandomPoint[Circle[]];
    ℛ = RegionDifference[Circle[initpoint, radius], Disk[]];
    p = RandomPoint[ℛ];
    Show[
      {Graphics[
         {Black, Circle[], 
          Purple, Circle[initpoint, radius], 
          Blue, Point @ (p = RandomPoint[ℛ]), 
          Red, Point @ initpoint}]], 
    {10}]]
```

However, I am not interested in generating images. I am only interested in finding the position of the blue point given a red point and the radius. The code I use is the same as before except that i do not show graphics.

```
With[{radius = 0.001},
Table[
   initpoint = RandomPoint[Circle[]];
   ℛ = RegionDifference[Circle[initpoint, radius], Disk[]];
   RandomPoint[ℛ], 
   {100}]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {9.02254, {{-0.6495, -0.761656}, {-0.122595, -0.99263}, <<96>>,{-0.142981,
0.990732}, {0.86886, 0.49706}}} *)
```

The above shows that it is taking 9 seconds to generate 100 configurations of blue given red. The process is extremely slow. Is there a way to speed the code up or is there a better algorithm?

Would be grateful for help.

Comment: Why not discretize the region first?

Comment: @J.M. if i discretize them first i get an error saying the first argument should be a parameter free region. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Region computations are often slow. Best to avoid them when possible, as it is for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better algorithm.

First a faster function for finding the blue point given the red point and the radius of the circle on which the blue point lies.

```
selectPt[cntr_, r_] :=
  Module[{pt = {0, 0}},
    While[Norm[pt] < 1, pt = RandomPoint[Circle[cntr, r]]]; 
    pt]
```

This constrains the blue point be further from the origin than the radius of the black circe; i.e., outside of the black circle.

```
With[{r = 0.2},
  Module[{cntr},
    GraphicsGrid[
      Table[
        cntr = RandomPoint[Circle[]];
        Graphics[
          {AbsolutePointSize[5],
           Black, Circle[],
           Purple, Circle[cntr, r],
           Blue, Point @ selectPt[cntr, r],
           Red, Point @ cntr}], {2}, {2}]]]]
```

[image: grid]

Timing

```
Module[{cntr},
  Table[cntr = RandomPoint[Circle[]]; selectPt[cntr .0011], {100}]]; 
// AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.055384, Null}`

Comment: But you still use `RandomPoint` which is way slower than just calculating `{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@RandomReal[2*Pi]`. The `RandomPoint` solution is ~ 30 times slower for 10000 points.

Comment: @BlacKow. Because it makes my code easier to understand, and it may be fast enough for the OP's purposes. I believe simplicity is preferable to speed as long as it fast enough.

Comment: Actually now I'm puzzled why the `RandomPoint@Circle[]` is so slow? `Trace` doesn't give anything useful ...

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks so much. I would only propose a small edit if you like. Maybe the `GraphicsGrid` can be implemented on the end result i.e. outside of `With`

Comment: @BlacKow thanks, i upvoted your answer

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need regions at all?

```
rBlack = 1.0;
rPurple = 0.1;    
randPoint[rB_, rP_][x_] := Module[{},
   rB {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@RandomReal[2*Pi] + rP {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@RandomReal[2*Pi]
   ];
Table[NestWhile[randPoint[rBlack, rPurple], {0, 0}, 
  Norm[#] < rBlack &], {100}]
```

So it takes a random point on black circle and adds (as vector) a random point on the purple circle. Then `NextWhile` repeats it until the point is actually beyond the black circle. Here is code that does the drawing - I modified the `randPoint` because I need the center of purple circle in addition to blue point coordinates.

```
randPointDraw[rB_, rP_][x_] := Module[{initPoint},
   initPoint = rB {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@RandomReal[2*Pi];
   {initPoint, initPoint + rP {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@RandomReal[2*Pi]}
   ];

GraphicsGrid@Partition[#, 3] &@ Table[Show[
 Graphics[{Black, Circle[{0, 0}, rBlack], Purple, Circle[#[[1]], rPurple], Blue, 
 Point[#[[2]]]}]] &@ NestWhile[randPointDraw[rBlack, rPurple], {0, 0}, 
    Norm[#[[2]]] < rBlack &], {9}]
```

[image]